# $\Sigma_n$ satisfaction predicate and $\Sigma_n$ elementarity

Tags: set-theory

In many places it is said that in ZF we can define a $\Sigma_n$-satisfaction predicate, $\models_n$ for each $n$. And an application of this using reflection principles is that for each $n$, there is some $V_\alpha$ that is $\Sigma_n$ elementary to $V$.  I have two questions about this.

(1) What is the precise meaning of "$\models_n$ is a $\sigma_n$-satisfaction predicate"? My understanding is that we can write down a formula "$\models_n (v_1, v_2)$" with two free variables such that ZF proves the following scheme.

$\forall x_1, ..., x_m (\models_n(u, \langle x_1, ..., x_m \rangle) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x_1, ..., x_m))$, where $u$ is the code of $\varphi$ and $\varphi$ has $x_1, ..., x_m$ free.

Is my understanding correct?

(2) If my understanding above is correct, then a natural idea for proving "there is a $V_\alpha$ that is $\Sigma_n$-elementary to $V$'' seems to be the following. By reflection principles, we have some $V_\alpha$ that reflects $\models_n (v_1, v_2)$. But I'm confused how we proceed from here. For example, let $\varphi(x_1, ..., x_m)$ be a $\Sigma_n$-formula. Suppose that $\varphi(a_1, ..., a_m)$ is true in $V$ for some $a_1, ..., a_m \in V_\alpha$. Then we have $\models_n (u, \langle a_1, ..., a_m \rangle)$ and so $V_\alpha \models (\models_n (u, \langle a_1, ..., a_m \rangle))$, where $u$ is the code of $\varphi$. But then can we conclude that $V_\alpha \models \varphi(a_1, ..., a_m)$? How do we know $V_\alpha$ also reflects $$\models_n(u, \langle x_1, ..., x_m \rangle) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x_1, ..., x_m)$$ for this particular $\varphi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it actually means is that $\vDash_n$ is a *$\Sigma_n$-universal formula.* We define $\Sigma_n$-formulas by formulas of the form
$$\exists x_0\forall x_1\cdots\mathsf{Q} x_{n-1}\phi(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1},\vec{y})$$
for an appropriate quantifier $\mathsf{Q}$. (Most definitions allow duplicated quantifiers, but it does not matter. Weak fragment of $\mathsf{ZF}$ like $\mathsf{KP}$ proves we can eliminate duplicated quantifiers of the same type.) We can define a truth predicate for $\Delta_0$-formulas using transitive sets like:
$$\vDash_{\Sigma_0}\phi(x)\iff \exists M [\text{$M$ is transitive such that $x\in M$, } M\vDash \phi(x)]$$
and we inductively (over the metatheory!) that
$$\vDash_{\Sigma_{n+1}}\exists x \phi(x,y) \iff \exists x \nvDash_{\Sigma_n}\lnot\phi(x,y).$$

Your understanding of the way the universal formula (or a partial truth predicate) works is correct. Regarding the reflection argument part, you can see that if $V_\alpha$ satisfies a sufficiently strong finite fragment of $\mathsf{ZF}$ (like $\mathsf{KP}$), then $V_\alpha$ will see the universal formula works, in the sense that for every $\Sigma_n$-formula $\phi$ we can find a natural number $i$ such that
$$V_\alpha \vDash [\vDash_{\Sigma_n }\phi_i(x) \iff \phi(x)].$$

Hence we can arrange the argument you stated as follows: Apply the reflection principle to the sufficiently strong finite fragment of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $\vDash_{\Sigma_n}(\phi_i,x)$, so we get $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha$ satisfies the fragment and
$$V_\alpha\vDash [\vDash_{\Sigma_n}(\phi_i,x)]\iff \vDash_{\Sigma_n}(\phi_i,x).$$
Since $V_\alpha$ satisfies the fragment, we get
$$V_\alpha \vDash [\phi_i(x)\leftrightarrow \vDash_{\Sigma_n}(\phi_i,x)].$$
Then you can conclude that $V_\alpha$ is $\Sigma_n$-elementary.

Comment: Thank you very much, but my worry is still that since "$\phi_i(x)\leftrightarrow \vDash_{\Sigma_n}(\phi_i,x)$" is a scheme, which has infinitely many instances, how do we know $V_\alpha$ reflects all of them? Are you saying this scheme is provable from a finite fragment of ZF? And can you explain how the universal formula plays a role here? Thanks again!

Comment: @user123 We do not reflect infinitely many formulas, but a single formula, namely, the universal $\Sigma_n$-formula. Once we reflect $\vDash_{\Sigma_n}$ to $V_\alpha$, then for every natural number $i$ (supposed to code a $\Sigma_n$-formula) and a parameter $x$ in $V_\alpha$, we have $\vDash_{\Sigma_n} \phi_i(x)$ iff $(\vDash_{\Sigma_n} \phi_i(x))^{V_\alpha}$.  Then with a trick I mentioned on my answer, we can replace $(\vDash_{\Sigma_n} \phi_i(x))^{V_\alpha}$ with $(\phi_i(x))^{V_\alpha}$.

Comment: Sorry I am still not clear. First, is $\models_{\Sigma_n}$ called a $\Sigma_n$-truth predicate or a universal $\Sigma_n$ formula? I understand the definition of$\models_{\Sigma_n}$, as defined here and in Jech. But I don't see a definition of $\Sigma_n$ universal formula anywhere, if they are not the same thing.  Second, I still do not understand your statement "then $V_\alpha$ will see the universal formula works, in the sense that ....". I might be missing something here. It'd be great if you can refer me to some texts where these are all written down. Thank you for your help, Hanul!

Comment: @user123 For the first question, yes, they mean the same thing. For the second, $V_\alpha$ satisfies the finite fragment that proves the schema $\vDash_{\Sigma_n} (\phi,a)\iff \phi(a)$, so the universal formula 'works' in this sense. You can see that the equivalence follows from a single finite fragment, or for example, $\mathsf{KP}$.

Comment: Ok, that helps a lot. One more question: the standard formulation of KP also has schemes in it so why is it a finite fragment?

Comment: Also, does KP prove $\vDash_{\Sigma_n} (\phi,a) \iff \phi(a)$ for every n? Or for each n, there is a different finite fragment that proves the scheme?

Comment: @user123 I mean $\mathsf{KP}$ without $\in$-induction scheme. I chose $\mathsf{KP}$ but the equivalence can be proven in a weaker fragment of it. $\mathsf{KP}$ with $\in$-induction restricted to $\Sigma_1$-formulas is finitely axiomatizable since we can use the universal $\Sigma_1$-formula in place of it.

Comment: @user123 $\mathsf{KP}$ indeed proves $\vDash_{\Sigma_n}(\phi,a)\iff \phi(a)$ for all $n$ and a $\Sigma_n$-formula $\phi$. I think $\mathsf{KP}$ is more than sufficient, and the equivalence should work over the primitive recursive set theory $\mathsf{PRS}$. (You may find the details of $\mathsf{PRS}$ from Anton Freund's thesis.)

Comment: Yeah, if this whole thing requires the finite axiomatization of KP then it does not sound like a standard textbook result to me...

Comment: @user123 Unfortunately I do not know if there is a standard reference for these facts, and it was a main trouble on learning about these stuff for me.